# Python colored grid over shapefile data plot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, shapefile

I have a dataset coming from a shape file `(.shp extention)` with coordinates. They should look something like this:

```
-70.62 -33.43
-70.59 -33.29
```

And so on. I already have developed a way to plot this data with `pyplot`, where each green dot represents a tree and each line a street, which looks like this:
[pyplot streets & trees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIUd0.png)

However, I need to draw a grid over it and color it's blocks depending on the amount of trees on each section. That way, the blocks with more trees would be colored with a stronger green, whereas the ones with less amount of trees would be a light green/yellow/red. Of course, these colors should be partially transparent, so the map isn't covered completely.

This is my code:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import shapely.geometry as sg

wgs84 = ccrs.Geodetic()
utm19s = ccrs.UTM(19, southern_hemisphere=True)

p_a = [-70.637, -33.449]
p_b = [-70.58, -33.415]

LL = utm19s.transform_point(p_a[0], p_a[1], wgs84)
UR = utm19s.transform_point(p_b[0], p_b[1], wgs84)

ax = plt.axes(projection=utm19s)
ax.set_extent([LL[0], UR[0], LL[1], UR[1]], crs=utm19s)

rds = shpreader.Reader('roadsUTM.shp')
trees = shpreader.Reader('treesUTM.shp')
rect = sg.box(LL[0], UR[0], LL[1], UR[1])

rds_sel = [r for r in rds.geometries() if r.intersects(rect)]
trees_sel = [t for t in trees.geometries() if t.intersects(rect)]

ax.add_geometries(rds_sel, utm19s, linestyle='solid', facecolor='none')
ax.scatter([t.x for t in trees_sel], [t.y for t in trees_sel], color = "green", edgecolor = "black", transform=utm19s)

plt.show()
```

TL;DR: A way to use shapefile encripted position data as plain numbers would solve part of my problem. Thanks.

**EDIT:** So I discovered that the data was already given in the UTM19S format. Should have researched a little bit before asking.
However, I still need to plot said grid over the map.